# why app names in DDMS file explorer ends with -1.apk or -2.apk

Tags: android, monitor, ddms, apk, android-4.2-jelly-bean

While going thorough **device "/data/app" folder** on my **rooted Galaxy S2(4.3)**, i am able to see all application names either ends with **-1.apk** or **-2.apk**

Can someone explain this,Why So??, also for new apps installed from google play, names ends with **-1.apk** or **-2.apk**
screenshot is as below.

[image]

Comment: Please consider to award the bounty since my answer helped you and there are only 2 days left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have one application installed say - googleplay. And if any updates of the same app comes afterwords, and if you update the app then Android will download the apk and renames it to apk-2.apk and replaces the currently installed (apk-1.apk) application with a newer one (apk-2.apk). 
I don't know exactly why Android does that but that is the done with names of apk - apk-1.apk and apk-2.apk. 
So It goes this way. 
1. You have one application installed say - playmusic then the apk in the "/data/app/" will be playmusic-1.apk 
2. One update came in playstore for playmusic. you selected - update. Updates start downloading. 
3. After downloading the update "Android OS" will install playmusic and update your app. and if you now see the "/data/app" folder it will be playmusic-2.apk 

As mentioned previously I don't know why Android OS does that but Its the mechanism.
Here by playmusic-1.apk and playmusic-2.apk means com.google.playmusic OR whatever the package name is. 
You can also try this by yourself.

**The answer of WHY**
Thanks to @Geobits the mystery is solved.  Android does because two apk files with the same name can not exist in the same directory.

Comment: +1, i tried your explanation and found it correct, however it will be great if we know why android does it in this way.

Comment: @Akhil I have done some research and found that its because of versioning of the apps, to keep track I guess. But I will have a look at this in detail and inform your as I will find it. I am pretty sure that its related to different versions of the app. But still I will find some concrete reason and tell you.

Comment: It could be to prevent overwriting the installed apk until the new one finishes downloading.

Comment: @Geobits Seems like you are right. Otherwise there is no such specific reason